# mongoose me crea un nuevo documento con findoneandupdate

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

antes tenia mi codigo funcionando para edicion ahora no se que paso que actuaalizo con monno goose usando todas las formas con update y set con findoneand update, findbyidandupdate y actualiza pero me crea otro documento no se por que :S NO Tengo la opcion new true habilitada por siacaso piensan eso aqui les dejo el codigo , les dejo la forma mas mongodb que pude, pero sin embargo me sigue creando otro doc con la modificacion y me deja dos docs, el viejo y el nuevo y me da errores despues.

```
router.post('/editar/:id', async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params
const result= await Caso.update({ _id: id }, {$set:{
    tienda:{
        codigo:req.body.desc_tienda,
        nombre:req.body.desc_tienda
    } ,
    ncaso: {
        numcaso:req.body.ncaso,
        codigocaso:req.body.desc_tienda+'-'+req.body.ncaso
    },
    encargado: req.user._id,
    tipo_caso: req.body.tipo_caso,
    rep_final: req.body.repfinal || '',
}

    console.log(result)
    req.flash('mensaje', 'Actualizado Correctamente')
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

siempre me crea un id nuevo es como si estuviera obviando el primer fragmento de filtro, con mongodb lo hago por consola y si lo toma bien :L

Comment: Será posible que estés recibiendo dos veces la misma petición?

Comment: En una de esas puede que no estés recibiendo el id. Creo que Update  crea un nuevo documento si mal no recuerdo.

Comment: si amigo era un detallito con el id jeje muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @Miguel, también puedes asegurarte a que no te cree un nuevo documento añadiendo la opción 'upsert': 
`Caso.update(<query>, <update>, { upsert: false})`
Por defecto esta a 'true', por lo que te inserta un documento nuevo si no existe, en cambio si lo pones a 'false' ya no lo haría.